# How do I create a key and secret so I can publish to a bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My code that I have inherited has the following:

```
var publisher = awspublish.create({
        key: 'xxx',
        secret: 'xxx',
        bucket: 'yyy',
        region: 'ap-southeast-1'
    });
```

But in S3 I am not sure. How do I create the key and secret ? and then make it so I can use these to publish to my bucket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create the key and secret in your AWS Console. They are not specific to S3.

Login to your AWS account and go to the 'Security Credentials' section. For an exact explanation on how to do this visit [this section](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSGettingStartedGuide/AWSCredentials.html) on the AWS website.